# Returning a Box<[Box<[JsValue]>]> doesn't work because IntoWasmAbi is not implemented

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to make a chunk method over a `JsValue` array. Is there are any way to pass modified array back to JavaScript?

That's what I am trying to do:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn chunk(array: Box<[JsValue]>, size: usize) -> Box<[Box<[JsValue]>]> {
    array
        .chunks(size)
        .map(|el| {
            el.iter()
                .map(|el| el.to_owned())
                .collect::<Box<[JsValue]>>()
        })
        .collect()
}
```

I get this during compilation:

```
the trait `wasm_bindgen::convert::traits::IntoWasmAbi` is not
implemented for
`std::boxed::Box<[std::boxed::Box<[wasm_bindgen::JsValue]>]>`
```

I also experimented with js_sys, but seems it takes even longer than a pure  JS implementation as it's just a JS API wrapper

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn chunk(array: Box<[JsValue]>, size: usize) -> Array {
    let root = Array::new();

    for chunk in array.chunks(size) {
        let arr = Array::new();

        for ch in chunk {
            arr.push(ch);
        }

        root.push(&arr);
    }

    root
}
```